# How to append a custom created plugin to existing plugins in TinyMCE editor using Javascript

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4, tinymce-plugins

I have created a new plugin for social sharing purpose. I need to append this plugin in TinyMCE editor. i.e, my new plugin need to appear in one of the toolbars along with plugins like 'Bold,Italic' etc. Please help me to resolve this issue as early as possible.

Answer (score 1):

The process for creating a plugin is documented here:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/advanced/creating-a-plugin/

What specific issue are you having that the documentation does not cover?